# Typescript: This expression is not callable. Type '{ getUserInfo(requestData: object): Promise<object>; }' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, service

I am having following issue, when i call to another function in typescript

This expression is not callable.
  Type '{ getUserInfo(requestData: object): Promise; }' has no call signatures.
in my index.ts

index.ts

```
  const fetchApiData = await getUserInfo(requestData)
```

service.ts

```
import { userInfoApi } from '../constants/api'
import request from '../utils/request'

export default {
  async getUserInfo(requestData: object): Promise<object> {
    return await request(userInfoApi, requestData, 'GET')
  },
}
```

request.ts

```
const request = (operation: string, data: object, method: any): Promise<object> => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    my.request({
      url: operation,
      data: data,
      method: method,
      success: function(res) {
        resolve(res)
      },
      fail: function(err) {
        reject(err)
      },
    })
  })
}

export default (operation: string, data: object, method: any): Promise<any> => {
  let timeHandle
  const timeout = 65 * 1000
  const promiseTimeout = new Promise(resolve => {
    timeHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        success: false,
        errorCode: 'NETWORK_TIMEOUT',
        errorMessage: 'Network Timeout',
      })
    }, timeout)
  })

  return Promise.race([
    request(operation, data, method).then(result => {
      clearTimeout(timeHandle)
      return result
    }),
    promiseTimeout,
  ])
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Check your import statement in the index.ts

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error is valid.

## Fix option 1 : Fix at call

Based on your error `Type '{ getUserInfo(requestData: object): Promise; }' has no call signatures` instead of calling `something(requestData)` you should be calling `something.getUserInfo(requestData)`.

## Fix option 2 : Fix at definition

Change:

```
export default {
  async getUserInfo(requestData: object): Promise<object> {
    return await request(userInfoApi, requestData, 'GET')
  },
}
```

to

```
export default async function getUserInfo(requestData: object): Promise<object> {
    return await request(userInfoApi, requestData, 'GET')
};
```

Comment: Brilliant Fix option 2 : Fix at definition

Answer (score 12):

In my case this was happening on TS 4.5 with the new Node ES Modules support. Basically, modules written in CommonJs import as objects, and default exports are not supported. To access what's proably the default export, in my case a function, use the `.default` property

Instead of

```
import chariot from 'EastIndiaCo'
```

I had to use:

```
import chariotPkg from 'EastIndiaCo'
const chariot = chariotPkg.default
```

To fix this upstream, the maintainer of EastIndiaCo should probably define package.json exports for modules.

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_exports

Comment: You could also just do `import { default as chariot } from 'EastIndiaCo'`

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby That behaves exactly the same as `import chariot from 'EastIndiaCo'` in all the environments I've used. On a vanilla Node JS module package, when importing a CommonJS package, the package gets loaded by the default ESMLoader which cannot reliably support some CJS default module specifications. Such as assigning an object to module.exports https://2ality.com/2022/10/commonjs-named-exports.html

Which means you would still have to use `charriot.default` with the code in your comment. Many loaders, compilers and bundlers have implement spotty/unpredictable workarounds for this

Answer (score 3):

My case was:

```
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```

Then I import it like this:

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```

and Error is gone.

Comment: I am getting this error from `jwt-decode` too, but already using it as the default import you've done. -- Probably this package needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

**service.ts**

```
export default async getUserInfo(requestData: object): Promise<object> {
    return await request(userInfoApi, requestData, 'GET')
};
```

**index.ts**

```
import getUserInfo from 'service.ts'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import  sha512  from "js-sha512";
```

I had error `This expression is not callable.` in code above.

I fix it with add brackets

```
import { sha512 } from "js-sha512";
```